# Orion Reports Error While Provisioning a Device

Tags: fiware-orion

I am following up with the FIWARE-IOTAgent-LWM2M tutorial available [here](https://fiware-iotagent-lwm2m.readthedocs.io/en/latest/deviceProvisioning/) trying to pre-provision an LWM2M device. I cloned github repo, installed dependencies and created `docker-compose.yml` file. All containers (including `lightweightm2m-iotagent`) started successfully.

However, when I tried provisioning the device using:

```
(curl localhost:4041/iot/devices -s -S --header 'Content-Type: application/json' \
  --header 'Accept: application/json' --header 'fiware-service: factory' --header 'fiware-servicepath: /robots' \
  -d @- | python -mjson.tool) <<EOF
{
  "devices": [
      {
        "device_id": "robot1",
        "entity_type": "Robot",
        "attributes": [
          {
            "name": "Battery",
            "type": "number"
          }
        ],
        "lazy": [
          {
            "name": "Message",
            "type": "string"
          }
        ],
        "commands": [
          {
            "name": "Position",
            "type": "location"
          }
        ],
      "internal_attributes": {
        "lwm2mResourceMapping": {
          "Battery" : {
            "objectType": 7392,
            "objectInstance": 0,
            "objectResource": 1
          },
          "Message" : {
            "objectType": 7392,
            "objectInstance": 0,
            "objectResource": 2
          },
          "Position" : {
            "objectType": 7392,
            "objectInstance": 0,
            "objectResource": 3
          }
        }
      }
    }
  ]
}
EOF
```

I get the following error:

```
{
    "message": "Request error connecting to the Context Broker: {\"code\":\"400\",\"reasonPhrase\":\"Bad Request\",\"details\":\"JSON Parse Error: unknown field: /contextRegistrations/contextRegistration/attributes/attribute/isDomain\"}",
    "name": "BAD_REQUEST"
}
```

I am not sure how to debug this. Any idea how to fix it?

**Question Edited:** Below is the docker-compose file I'm using.

```
version: "3.1"

services:
        mongo:
                image: mongo:3.6
                command: --nojournal
                ports: 
                 - "27017:27017"
                expose:
                 - "27017"
        orion:
                image: fiware/orion
                links:
                 - mongo
                ports: 
                 - "1026:1026"
                command: -dbhost mongo -logLevel DEBUG
                depends_on:
                 - mongo
                expose: 
                 - "1026"
        lightweightm2m-iotagent:
                image: telefonicaiot/lightweightm2m-iotagent
                hostname: idas
                links:
                 - orion
                expose: 
                 - "4041"
                 - "5684"
                ports: 
                 - "4041:4041"
                 - "5684:5684/udp"
        mosquitto:
                image: ansi/mosquitto
                ports: 
                 - "1883:1883"
                expose: 
                 - "1883"
```

Comment: I think I have an idead of the problem cause but, before anwering, could you please edit your question post to provide a link to the docker-compose.yml file you are using? Thx!

Comment: Hi @fgalan I added the docker-compose.yml file I used.

Comment: This problem has been solved after updating the lightweightm2m-iotagent image.

Answer (score 0):

It is a [known issue](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/issues/701), already fixed in master branch.

It has been [fixed recently](https://github.com/telefonicaid/iotagent-node-lib/pull/703) on November 7th, 2018. On the other hand `telefonicaiot/lightweightm2m-iotagent:latest` (and `telefonicaiot/lightweightm2m-iotagent` should default to `latest`) last update at the time of writting this is November 13th, 2018 so it should include the fix.

Probably your `telefonicaiod/lightweightm2m-iotagent` image is out of date. Pulling it again from Dockerhub should solve the problem.

Comment: Hi @fgalan,
Pulling the image agent solves the problem, but generate the following error again:
' ' ' {
    "message": "Cannot read property 'findOne' of undefined",
    "name": "TypeError"
} ' ' ' Reported here.. #17

Comment: I'd suggest to open a new question for the new problem.